# How can one interpret the results from a solved system of ODEs using integrate.odeint?

Tags: python, scipy, ode

I am solving the system of Lorentz equations (3 ordinary differential equations) and my code is below.

```
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import numpy as np
from numpy import array, arange

def Lorentz(state,t):          #Define the function for the derivatives for each equation
    u = state[0]               
    v = state[1]
    w = state[2]               #Give each differential equation (u, v and w) a state.

    a = 5.0
    b = 0.9
    c = 8.2                    #Define the constants a, b and c.

    du = -a*(u - v)
    dv = c*u - v - u*w
    dw = -b*w + u*v            #Define the differential equations u, v and w.

    return [du, dv, dw]        #Return the set of differential equations that the function defines.

state0 = [0.0, 1.0, 2.0]       #Define the set of inition conditions for u, v and w, respectively.
t = arange(0.0, 10.0, 0.7)     #Solve the equations from t=0 to t=10.

print odeint(Lorentz, state0, t)
```

When I run the code with

```
t = arange(0.0, 10.0, arg)
```

the number of results I get depends on the value of "arg". If I choose a large value I get a small number of results. For anything above 10.0 this gives an array [0.0, 1.0, 2.0].

For lower values the number of rows in the array gets larger, but the first row stays the same. For really low values like 0.01 I get a huge array of numbers, always with the first row as [0.0, 1.0, 2.0].

What are all the numbers in the array? Surely there's only one solution for each equation to a system of differential equations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are aware that the result of an ODE integration is a function?

The row `k` (starting with `0`) corresponds to the function values at time `t[k]`. The first row at time `t[0]` contains the initial value `state0`.